# msiexec does not install into the directory

Tags: windows, windows-installer

I am using this command to install `msi` application

```
msiexec /i mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.2.9-signed.msi /qb APPDIR=D:\MSI_INSTALL
```

But it still installs in the default directory directory on disk `C:\`

`Windows Installer V 5.0`

What is the problem? `TARGETDIR` does not work either, `INSTALLLOCATION` too

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#id2):

```
msiexec.exe /q /i mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.2.10-signed.msi ^
            INSTALLLOCATION="C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2.10\" ^
            ADDLOCAL="all"
```

Answer (score -1):

`ROOTDRIVE=D:` lets you install on D:

`INSTALLDIR=D:\MSI_INSTALL` will change the install location in most cases.
Also enable logging with `/lv* %windir%\mongodb.log`